# Does Ubuntu One sync symbolic links with Windows?

Tags: windows, ubuntu-one

I noticed that the Windows Ubuntu One client currently doesn't support folders outside of the main `~/Ubuntu One` folder.  I'm wondering if I can symlink to my other folders from within `~/Ubuntu One` and have Ubuntu One synchronize them properly.  If this isn't supported yet, is it planned for the future?

Comment: No I don't think so.

Comment: you should probably rephrase your question as **"Does Ubuntu One sync symbolic links with Windows?"**.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Symlinks won't be followed in Ubuntu One for Windows. The way it will work is the same way as the existing Ubuntu One for Ubuntu: you'll be able to mark any folder as synchronised with Ubuntu One. We're working on that right now. :-)

Comment: Great.  Will you send a notification to beta users when you finish with that?

Comment: The windows client currently has part of the code that will notify you about updates, will download them and install them. As soon as we have updates for this, we will do so. I'm also planning to move to use omaha rather than the custom code that we currently have.

Answer (score 3):

(removed - consider Stuart's answer)

---

Say for example you want to synchronise `/home/matt/test`, instead of making a symbolic link to this directory in `~/Ubuntu One`, make `test` be a symlink to `~/Ubuntu One/test`, which is a proper directory.

that's

```
mkdir Ubuntu\ One/test
ln -s Ubuntu\ One/test test
cd /home/matt/test
```

This should alaways work, since Ubuntu One doesn't need to know about any of it.

Answer (score 2):

Until Ubuntu One for Windows implements a way to mark folders for synchronization, you could try creating Junctions (a sort of special link) on the folders you you wish to synchronize.

To do this without having to use the Windows command prompt or a separate microsoft toolkit, look for a program called Link Shell Extension (which seems to work in 32-bit and 64-bit Windows). After installing it, you can simply right-click-and-drag any folder into your Ubuntu One folder, and then select Drop --> Junction.

Individual files can be sync'd as well; the only difference is that you would select Drop --> Hard Link after right-click-dragging the desired files.

Hope this helps!