# How can I synchronize Windows links (.lnk) to 12.10 using Ubuntu One?

Tags: 12.10, ubuntu-one, symbolic-link, filelink

## My problem

UbuntuOne does not synchronize Windows link files (`.lnk`). Now, I do not expect UbuntuOne to synchronize the actual links by changing an `.lnk` file to a linux `symlink`, nor do I do expect UbuntuOne to copy the actual target file in the Library (as though it were a hard link). But I *would love to* have UbuntuOne copy the `.lnk` files themselves.

## The use case

I have an identical directory structure on my windows computer (@work) and my 12.10 (@home). At work I have a folder called *Library* which contains all my pdfs. When I am working on something I put a link to that file in the current working directory. That's nice because all my files are easy to reach and I know which files I have referred to.

That would allow me to see what files I quoted. On the long run it would allow me to use a script to convert the .lnk files to symbolic links on 12.10.

As a part of this question: do you have a) a proposal of a batch script to convert windows `.lnk files` to text files and b) a script that converts that text file to a `symlink` on 12.10. I could run the first script on W$ and the second on 12.10. Or do you have a better solution?

## The background

I have read the following questions (and their answers) and I think this is *not* a duplicate, because I don't want the target file (the file the link refers to) to be copied, but simply the .lnk file itself.

- [Does Ubuntu One follow symlinks if synchronizing a folder?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29062/does-ubuntu-one-follow-symlinks-if-synchronizing-a-folder/29065#29065)
- [Does Ubuntu One sync symbolic links with Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15891/does-ubuntu-one-sync-symbolic-links-with-windows)
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/205330/can-i-synchronize-links-with-ubuntu-one (a bit similar, but closed)

Comment: Two new things: a) are lnk files now synchronized; it seems that some synchronized. Is this a new feature? b) I have just found a bug/feature request for lnk implementation: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=47894

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do not currently have any proposals to convert lnk files to text files, but you're looking in the right direction. What you could probably do is write a script that watches your U1 directory and calls [FindFirstFileNameW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364421%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on each file (or configured files) to find out what files have links and what the links are called. Then write that to a file which is synchronized by U1, then on your other clients (your linux machine(s)), open that file when it's changed and maintain your file->link setup.

Comment: Hi Brian. Just the other day I noticed that some of my `.lnk` files were copied to my ubuntu desktop. Is it just me forgetting about something I did in the past, or has this feature been implemented in U1? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Synchronizing your .lnk file to ubuntu would not help you achieve your goal because reading the contents of those files from ubuntu is not easy (if it's possible at all).

So, it may be a better idea to do what you propose, export the data in those .lnk files to something, then read it in ubuntu and create symlinks.

A quick search doesn't tell me anything very interesting about how to actually do it, but I'll ask around.

Comment: hi Roberto, thanks for your interest. any news?